# Limiting Web Worker CPU Utilization?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, html, web-worker

I'm looking at writing a long running CPU intensive operation using Web Workers and it does seem to be possible to push a client's CPU to 100% with these. (See [Can Web Workers utilize 100% of a multi-core CPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871452/can-web-workers-utilize-100-of-a-multi-core-cpu))

Does anyone know of any effective ways to limit the CPU utilization of web workers?

Comment: Before trying to give you an answer, did you ask yourself if loading the client with such tasks is a reasonable thing?

Comment: I'm looking at this specifically in terms of research on the feasibility of distributed computation over clients built in HTML5. I'm actually currently trying to figure out how reasonable of project this is, and the CPU utilization of the clients is my current issue.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there is a way.

Structure your computations so they can be done by repeatedly calling a function which performs a part of the work before exiting. Just before exiting, use setTimeout to schedule a new call on the worker function in a few milliseconds. The wait time can be adjusted to use nore or less CPU time.

```
function doWork () {
  var timer = new Date ();

 // do n cyles of work here


 timer = new Date () - timer; // time spent working 
 setTimeout (doWork, timer);  // wait an equivalent time for 50% processor load
}
```

Comment: This would be entirely dependent on the client's hardware correct? I'm hoping to find a way that could lower utilization to a specific percentage for all clients.

Comment: By hardware, I presume you mean performance. Yes but you could measure the time spent working then wait an appropriate time to average the load. I have updated the example.